# No output in PDF for Jasper Report + Table Component + Dataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate the *JR* report with Table component. But no data is getting displayed in generated PDF file. No error as well.

Please tell what I am doing wrong here?

**Data source** : JavaBeans (POJO)

**JRXML file**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
    name="org-report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20"
    bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="test-data-set">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="orgDskUsage" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgDskUsage]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="orgId" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgId]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="orgMsgSize" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgMsgSize]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="orgName" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>

    <field name="orgDskUsage" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgDskUsage]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="orgId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="orgMsgSize" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgMsgSize]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="orgName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orgName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>

    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="297" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Organisation Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="179" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="91" y="15" width="360" height="140"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="test-data-set">
                        <!-- <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(OrgDataSource.getOrgList())]]></dataSourceExpression> -->
                         <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table_TH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Org Id]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{orgId}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table_TH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Org Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{orgName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table_TH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Msg Dsk usage]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{orgDskUsage}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table_TH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Msg Size]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{orgMsgSize}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20"/>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Report.log**

```
2013-06-01 15:16:11,804 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] JRXmlDigesterFactory: Using SAX parser factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory
2013-06-01 15:16:11,805 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] JRXmlDigesterFactory: Instantiated SAX parser factory of type org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
2013-06-01 15:16:11,806 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] JRXmlDigesterFactory: Adding components schema at jar:file:/opt/opennms/lib/jasperreports-3.7.6.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/       components/components.xsd
2013-06-01 15:16:11,806 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] JRXmlDigesterFactory: Instantiating grammar pool of type org.apache.xerces.util.XMLGrammarPoolImpl for cache key                 WebAppClassLoader=opennms@49ab4552
2013-06-01 15:16:11,849 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] SpringExtensionsRegistry: Getting bean org.opennms.netmgt.jasper.OnmsQueryExecutorFactoryBundle#0 as extension of type net.sf.   jasperreports.engine.query.QueryExecuterFactoryBundle
2013-06-01 15:16:11,850 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] SpringExtensionsRegistry: Getting bean org.opennms.netmgt.jasper.OnmsQueryExecutorFactoryBundle#0 as extension of type net.sf.   jasperreports.engine.query.QueryExecuterFactoryBundle
2013-06-01 15:16:11,852 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,853 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,853 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,853 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,853 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,854 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,854 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,854 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,854 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,854 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,855 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,855 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,855 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,855 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,855 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,856 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,856 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,856 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,856 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,856 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,857 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,857 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,857 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,858 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,859 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,859 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,859 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,859 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,859 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,860 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,860 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,860 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,860 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Pushing report context for dataset name test-data-set
2013-06-01 15:16:11,860 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] TableReportContextXmlRule: Popping report context
2013-06-01 15:16:11,862 DEBUG [qtp1926506456-396] SpringExtensionsRegistry: Getting bean org.opennms.netmgt.jasper.OnmsQueryExecutorFactoryBundle#0 as extension of type net.sf.   jasperreports.engine.query.QueryExecuterFactoryBundle
```

Answer (score 0):

your problems is that you do not have any Queries to pull any data.  You Defined your Fields but you have nothing to fill them.

in your Base report you need some data so that your table will show up other wise jasper thinks that the report is blank, I normally use something very simple like

```
select sysdate from dual
```

then in your dataset you also need a query to pull your data

```
select orgDskUsage,orgID,orgMsgSize,OrgName from dual
```

Of course you need to change the from to be your tables

in your code add Line 25

```
<![CDATA[select orgDskUsage,orgID,orgMsgSize,OrgName from dual]]>
```

and line 41

```
<![CDATA[select sysdate from dual ]]>
```